# Banner bleeds through top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The banners in the theme are bleeding through the top bar in Chrome on OSX.

[image]

[image]

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210346/top-bar-with-double-color (should be fixed, but I doubt anyone's building over the weekend)

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks.  I didn't see that.

Comment: no responce for more than 2 days, i doubt this will ?

Comment: @Bala, According to your MSO post, it is fixed in the dev versions.  They will do a new build for live, regression test, and then start pushing it out.  The fix to live can take a few days, especially when there is a weekend in the way.

Comment: do you still see this problem after hard refreshing? I've fixed it last week should be on live now.

Comment: @MPD I found out why: there hasn't been a production build since I pushed the fix to dev last Friday. It should be out today(Monday). I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Seems it's time to make it status-completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this. Though it seems the old background image is cached. I just pushed another fix with the css cache breaker in it.

Comment: Confirmed - works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is a global problem that is affecting some themes.  Accoding to [Top bar with double color?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210346/top-bar-with-double-color), the problem is fixed and will be live soon.